# 'Would' and 'might': differences and usage

Tags: conditionals

Let us suppose that a hurricane is expected tomorrow in the place you are visiting.

Would it be better that you say either "*I think it **would** be better to leave early.*" or "*I think it **might** be better to leave early.*"

Comment: There's no difference between your two examples. Concentrate on the first sentence in your question text, which is completely ungrammatical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - are you so kind to tell me what is wrong? Is it ungrammatical the future (It will arrive ...)?

Comment: *"[Let us] suppose that a hurricane is expected tomorrow in the place you are visiting"*. It's awkward to get "natural" phrasing for what you want to express there, but your version just looks like a word-by-word translation (from your native language, I suppose).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yes, you are right, I have translated the first sentence word-by-word from my native language. Thank you so much.

Comment: Define *better*. The two mean different things. Asking which would be better is like asking which would be better: eating a carrot or flying a kite. The question should be closed because it is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"I think it **would** be better" implies a stronger opinion than "I think it **might** be better".

"Might" is normally used when trying to make a suggestion respectfully, as in "You **might** consider packing an umbrella next time."